# Start nodejs using shell command and then what?

Tags: node.js

I have installed nodejs on my server and installed my first app which is built upon Express.

My app includes a `.listen()` function

I know I must instantiate my app using `node index.js` in the shell and once I do that, the shell window cannot receive new commands unless I stop the node process using `Ctrl+C`

1. Once the node app is started, will the app continue to run on its own if I close the shell window?
2. Once the node app is started, how can I get the control back on shell commands in the current window without stopping the node app that is running?

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is _hardly_ a question about Node.js. Sounds more like you need a tutorial on basic terminal use. Which shell are you using?

Comment: I am using Putty, should I use the node console instead?

Comment: Have a look at [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) or [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Comment: [An oddly relevant read.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89483/keeping-a-process-running-after-putty-or-terminal-has-been-closed)

Comment: @Vishwanath many thanks for leading me towards the right direction (I really do not understand the downvotes...)

Comment: Upvoted to compensate. Maybe the language was not clear.